# Saving desktopCapturer to video file in Electron

Tags: javascript, electron, getusermedia, mediastream

The [desktopCapturer](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/desktop-capturer.md) api example shows how to write a screen capture stream to a `<video>` element.

```
// In the renderer process.
var desktopCapturer = require('electron').desktopCapturer;

desktopCapturer.getSources({types: ['window', 'screen']}, function(error, sources) {
  if (error) throw error;
  for (var i = 0; i < sources.length; ++i) {
    if (sources[i].name == "Electron") {
      navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({
        audio: false,
        video: {
          mandatory: {
            chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',
            chromeMediaSourceId: sources[i].id,
            minWidth: 1280,
            maxWidth: 1280,
            minHeight: 720,
            maxHeight: 720
          }
        }
      }, gotStream, getUserMediaError);
      return;
    }
  }
});

function gotStream(stream) {
  document.querySelector('video').src = URL.createObjectURL(stream);
}

function getUserMediaError(e) {
  console.log('getUserMediaError');
}
```

I tried to replace the gotStream function with the following:

```
function gotStream(stream) {
  var fs = require('fs');
  fs.writeFileSync('vid.mp4', stream);
}
```

This creates a text file with `[object MediaStream]` as the contents.

How can I record this stream and save to a file on disk?

Comment: I answerd similar question.
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41053078/1055501)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12101012/266535

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36523834/266535

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I answered my own question with the help of Demian's link to MediaRecorder as well as other related questions.

Below is an excerpt from [magnemite](https://github.com/styfle/magnemite/blob/master/src/renderer.ts) with some minor simplifications and converted from TypeScript to JavaScript ES5 for better understanding to most readers.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var electron = require('electron');

var SECRET_KEY = 'Magnemite';

var recorder;
var blobs = [];

function startRecording() {
    var title = document.title;
    document.title = SECRET_KEY;

    electron.desktopCapturer.getSources({ types: ['window', 'screen'] }, function(error, sources) {
        if (error) throw error;
        for (let i = 0; i < sources.length; i++) {
            let src = sources[i];
            if (src.name === SECRET_KEY) {
                document.title = title;

                navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({
                    audio: false,
                    video: {
                        mandatory: {
                            chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',
                            chromeMediaSourceId: src.id,
                            minWidth: 800,
                            maxWidth: 1280,
                            minHeight: 600,
                            maxHeight: 720
                        }
                    }
                }, handleStream, handleUserMediaError);
                return;
            }
        }
    });
}

function handleStream(stream) {
    recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
    blobs = [];
    recorder.ondataavailable = function(event) {
        blobs.push(event.data);
    };
    recorder.start();
}

function stopRecording() {
    recorder.stop();
    toArrayBuffer(new Blob(blobs, {type: 'video/webm'}), function(ab) {
        var buffer = toBuffer(ab);
        var file = `./videos/example.webm`;
        fs.writeFile(file, buffer, function(err) {
            if (err) {
                console.error('Failed to save video ' + err);
            } else {
                console.log('Saved video: ' + file);
            }
        });
    });
}

function handleUserMediaError(e) {
    console.error('handleUserMediaError', e);
}

function toArrayBuffer(blob, cb) {
    let fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = function() {
        let arrayBuffer = this.result;
        cb(arrayBuffer);
    };
    fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
}

function toBuffer(ab) {
    return Buffer.from(ab);
}

// Record for 7 seconds and save to disk
startRecording();
setTimeout(function() { stopRecording() }, 7000);
```

This will record the current electron window for 7 seconds and save to disk.

Comment: Anyone make a clue of how to record only audio and not video to a audio file output? I wish to avoid the overhead of recording audio and video and only "export" the audio.

Comment: Looks like the creation of the buffer should be triggered by the onstop event of the recorder to avoid the buffer to be empty.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [MediaRecorder API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder)

You should convert that stream to binary chunks.

Answer (score 1):

[The desktopCapturer example](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/desktop-capturer#desktopcapturer) shows how to get a `Blob`. You then need to convert the `Blob` to something accepted by `fs.writeFile`. The following is short and efficient:

```js
fs.writeFile(filepath, Buffer.from(await blob.arrayBuffer()), ...);
```

Comment: I forgot to update my answer since I fixed that in [2018](https://github.com/styfle/magnemite/commit/a6f08c9c4a3779206b80380a9efc949dc63ecd62). Also, didn't realize that `blob.arrayBuffer()` was introduced in [2019](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/arrayBuffer), very nice!

Comment: @styfle I removed my comment about your answer, since you updated it :-)

Answer (score 1):

just a reminder you should use writestream upon on dataavailable to **avoid memory leak**.

when calling `mediaRecorder.start()` you can pass a number that represents interval to trigger the `ondataavailable`

Example:

```js
// Assuming you already created the mediaStream

const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);

// starting the recording
mediaRecorder.start(1_000); // 1 second interval to trigger the dataavailable

// Create the stream file;
let writeStream = createWriteStream('your_path'); // Import this from 'fs'

const handleData = async (e: BlobEvent) => {
  const arrayBuffer = await e.data.arrayBuffer(); // convert to array buffer
  writeStream.write(Buffer.from(arrayBuffer));
}

const handleStop = () => {
  writeStream.end(() => {
    writeStream = null; // Cleanup the writeStream once done.
  });
}

mediaRecorder.addEventListener('dataavailable', handleData);
mediaRecorder.addEventListener('stop', handleStop);
```

In this approach you can record long recordings without having a lag issue since you no longer storing buffers in memory.