# Save captured video to file in Electron

Tags: node.js, video, webrtc, electron, recordrtc

I want to save a video that is captured from webcam to a local file. So far I have been able to:

1. Create a stream with `getUserMedia`
2. Encapsulate the stream with `RecordRTC`
3. Get blob from `RecordRTC`

I cannot figure out how to save the video to a file though. Calling `save()` on `RecordRTC` allows me to download the video file, but I want everything to happen in nodejs for further processing. The file is playable, regardless. I tried to write the blob and dataURL to file, but that file is not playable.

Answer (score 10):

The [MediaRecorder](https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-record/#MediaRecorderAPI) class implemented in Chromium and thus Electron, can support your use case. Saving the media as a file is not only possible but arguably trivial:

```js
const recorder = new MediaRecorder(await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia());
const blob_reader = new FileReader();
const storage_stream = require("fs").createWriteStream(path);
const blobs = [];
blob_reader.addEventListener("load", ev => {
    storage_stream.write(Buffer.from(ev.currentTarget.result));
    if(blobs.length) ev.currentTarget.readAsArrayBuffer(blobs.shift());
});
recorder.addEventListener("dataavailable", ev => {
    if(blob_reader.readyState != 1) blob_reader.readAsArrayBuffer(ev.data);
    else blobs.push(ev.data);
});
```

Alternatively, instead of using the `FileReader` class to obtain array buffer objects corresponding to their blob equivalents, one may use `Blob.prototype.arrayBuffer`, which makes for even shorter and thus arguably more readable source code:

```js
const recorder = new MediaRecorder(await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia());
const storage_stream = require("fs").createWriteStream(path);
recorder.addEventListener("dataavailable", async ev => {
    storage_stream.write(Buffer.from(await ev.data.arrayBuffer()));
});
```

No matter the variant chosen from the two above, short of what I consider a technically expendable and undesired (but necessary) step of converting `Blob` objects to `ArrayBuffer` equivalents in order to wrap the latter in a `Buffer`, this is as efficient as the API implementation itself is -- the JavaScript machine itself does no heavy lifting here.

Remarks and explanations on the solution proposed:

- There won't be any action until you actually start the media recorder by issuing a call to the [`MediaRecorder.start`](https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-record/#dom-mediarecorder-start) method. Note that the snippet is made to work with multiple generated blobs, if needed -- using a timeslice (first argument to `start`) of 1 second may be a good idea, depending. Such timeslice allows you to do proper streaming of data, as opposed to getting a potentially gigantic single blob worth of encoded video stream stored in process memory (which is what you get if you omit the `timeslice` parameter to `start`).
- As soon as a call to `start` is issued (with a timeslice), the resulting file will start growing "on disk", depending on the timeslice value and lengths of intermediate buffers.
- A `MediaRecorder` object, as part of encoding media, generates [blobs](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#dfn-Blob) which, for one reason or another, aren't very "consumable" by many other APIs, so we have to convert them to something that is consumable, in this case objects of the more convenient for us [`ArrayBuffer`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-arraybuffer-constructor) class.
- If using `FileReader`, since conversion of a blob into an array buffer is asynchronous, we have a queue of blobs that is duly converted on a [FIFO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO_(computing_and_electronics)) basis.
- `require("fs")` gets us a Node.js module, "fs" is not a module otherwise available in your Web browser, at least not according to a Web standard or draft thereof that I know of. That's the module, however, that allows us to dump the resulting array buffers into a file.
- The perhaps inconspicuous expression `Buffer.from(...)` is more than meets the eye here -- there is no `Buffer` class in the Web API space, it's a Node.js class that is able to wrap an `ArrayBuffer` as a view (no data copying). This is necessary because you can't write an `ArrayBuffer` into a file stream directly.
- A concatenation of data generated by a media recorder object is a *valid* media container (with respect to the MIME type of the recorder object), so just handing these data to the stream, when done in proper order of course, is sufficient to get us valid media container file (e.g. a `.webm` or an `.mp4`).
- The resulting file is, however, a so called transport stream -- some video players may or may not be able to reliably or efficiently seek on the data. `ffmpeg`, however, can trivially postprocess such files by indexing them and patching them accordingly. I consider such step optional -- there is nothing inherently wrong with a transport stream like the ones generated by the snippet above.
- The `path` property/variable passed to `createWriteStream` above denotes the path to the file you want to save the video to.

I have tested the snippet with the 3.0.4 version of Electron on Windows 10.

An alternative approach to saving the media as a file -- which interestingly works with a Web browser of a fairly modern make, too -- is to concatenate the blobs provided by the recorder into a single blob and let user download the entire product using the [`URL.createObjectURL`](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#dfn-createObjectURL) method. I'd argue, however, that this approach and the one illustrated above, are not equivalent in their function or capability -- I am not 100% confident about how blobs are implemented in different user agents -- whether backed by physical/virtual RAM, for example -- media files can grow very large and if, contained in blobs and referenced with URLs, these need to be stored in RAM in their entirety, well that's a potentially latent resource exhaustion fault. In comparison, writing a file piecemeal shouldn't naturally suffer from such constraints. Anyway, I leave the application of `createObjectURL` an exercise to the reader, it should be rather trivial, everything else being in place.

Comment: This works great! But I am looking for that "trivial" way to process created .webm file using ffmpeg into something with the timeline that player can use to seek to.

Comment: Then you should create a question post, clearly stating your requirements :)

Comment: thank you! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66378240/generating-timestamps-in-webm-transport-stream-with-ffmpeg

Answer (score 2):

I have never used the RecordRTC.
Worked in use native(JavaScript) MediaRecorder API to record.
I wrote [sample](https://github.com/turbographics2000/Electron-MediaStream-Record-Sample)

Comment: It looks promising, I will try it out. Thanks Tanaka :)

Comment: You should post a code snippet here in case the link goes dead or the repo is deleted. That way future readers can see the answer.